# Docker-compose linking service into dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am pretty new to docker, and I am trying to make a container with multiple apps.

Let say that my docker-compose file is like this :

```
version: '2'

services:
    myapp:
        build: ./dockerfiles/myapp
        volumes:
          - ./www:/var/www
          - ./logs:/var/log
          - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
          - ./php:/etc/php5
          - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
        ports:
            - "8082:8000"
            - "6606:3306"
        links:
            - mysql:mysql
            - php:php
            - nginx:nginx
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: M@yW3Bw35t
            MYSQL_USER: replymwp
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ZSzLPoOi9wlhFaiJ
    php:
        image: php:5.6-fpm
        links:
            - mysql:db
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        links:
            - php:php
```

Now, in myapp DockerFile, I want to install a package that needs mysql.

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y apt-show-versions

RUN apt-get install -y wget 
RUN wget http://repo.ajenti.org/debian/key -O- | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://repo.ajenti.org/ng/debian main main ubuntu" >>         /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y ajenti

RUN apt-get install -y ajenti-v ajenti-v-ftp-vsftpd ajenti-v-php-fpm ajenti-v-mysql

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["ajenti-panel"]
```

Now the problem is, when docker try to build my image, it install php, mysql etc... even if I link it in my docker-compose file. And secondly, when it try to install mysql, It prompt for a master password and stay blocked at this step, even if I fill something...

Maybe am I totally wrong in my way of using it?

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: group your RUN, as Debian Jessie is not just out, doing `RUN apt-get update ` and then `RUN apt-get install -y wget` is like typing those 2 commands on 2 different computers, so no update of the repositories! See the Dockerfiles best practices at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: check the doc at https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Comment: Oh I see, huge mistake... thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `ajenti` has a dependency on mysql, so if you do `apt-get install ajenti`, it tries to satisfy that dependency. Specifically you are installing `ajenti-v-mysql`, which does seem to have a mysql dependency

Because you want to run mysql seperate, you might need to do `--no-install-recommends` ? This is a flag voor `apt-get`, so you'd get something like

```
apt-get install <packagename> --no-install-recommends
```

This would mean you get NO dependencies, so you might need to figure out which other depenencies you need.

The `php-fpm` has the same issue, I suppose that whole line which includes `ajenti-v-php-fpm` is a bit too much?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed ajenti-v-mysql and others (and just let ajenti-v for testing). I tried with  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --nodeps \ ajenti \ ajenti-v but It prompt : E: Command line option --nodeps is not understood

Comment: my bad, that seems to be a `dpkg` option. you need `--no-install-recommends` i think.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it works when I remove ajenti-v-mysql and others, but my problem is that ajenti doesn't see any instance of mysql. Ajenti has a terminal where I can run shell command, but mysql isn't available. It seems that tehre is not link between my two containers...

Comment: Finally, I create a full dockerfile to build my container, it was really easier and it is working well. I used export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive and debconf-set-selections to set the mysql conf without prompting anything.Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on using separate mysql and php containers, then why are you still including the installation in the mpapp dockerfile on this line:

`RUN apt-get install -y ajenti-v ajenti-v-ftp-vsftpd ajenti-v-php-fpm ajenti-v-mysql`

If you're going to use mysql and php containers then you don't need them in your app. This should also take care of your second problem about being prompted for mysql password.

Keep in mind that you will need to change the hostnames of mysql and your php configuration from your myapp configuration. I think you might be better off looking for a tutorial for setting up docker compose, you'll have to look yourself to find the most suitable but something like [this](http://www.samueledney.com/2016/01/21/trying-out-docker-php-and-mysql/) would give you a good start.